# Do the states $|01\rangle$, $|10\rangle$ span the space of a single photon?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-optics

i nave included some simple information about Fock states for photons in a work.

I wanted to know if:

- in the context of a beam splitter when we suppose to have only one photon, always entering from the same port, does the states
  $$| 0 \rangle \otimes |1\rangle $$
  $$
  | 1 \rangle \otimes |0\rangle
  $$
  form a basis for the output states?
  In particular i'm asking this because to use these states as the states of a qubit i need to associate them with the computational basis;
- if i want to explicit the untouched polarization of the photon, supposing the beam splitter is not polarizing, how can i "extract" it from Fock states?
  I thought i could write for the entering state:
  $$
  | 0 \rangle \otimes (|\psi \rangle_{POL} \otimes |1\rangle)
  $$
  and the analogue for output states.
  Is that correct?

Thanks in advance.

(If you answer, please add references to book, thanks)